# Gradle downloads everytime I import the project into eclipse as gradle?

Tags: eclipse, command-line, gradle, gradlew

I was trying to configure few of gradle projects on my local machine. This is what I did:

**Command Line:**

Changed the directory to project I want to build.

```
./gradlew build
```

It started downloading the first time which is very normal. Now, everytime I try to build this project or any of the other project which uses the same version, it first downloads the gradle.

**Eclipse**

I tried to import the Gradle project, then **BuildModel** it started downloading the gradle and now again each time I try other projects or even try to import the same project again, it starts downloading.

**Question?**

Is it normal or environment is broken? If later is the case, how can I fix it?

Comment: This should only happen if all the projects you are building specify different Gradle download URLs (the required Gradle version is part of that URL) in their `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. Even then, it should only happen once per project. Downloaded Gradle distributions are stored in `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`.

Comment: Exactly but this is not the case. That's why posted the question :(

Comment: Impossible to say what's going on from here. I suggest to check the `--debug` log and the `dists` directory. Make sure that the `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists` path is good, distributions are downloaded to that directory, and your filesystem isn't somehow misconfigured. Also make sure that your system doesn't have a misconfigured `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable (defaults to `~/.gradle`). Perhaps you can also provide the exact Gradle command line output/Eclipse screenshot that makes you think it's redownloading Gradle.